# How to return decoded string based on encoded string Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, decode

For x = '4[kl]', the output should be  'klklklkl'
For s = '3[k2[b]]', the output should be 'kbbkbbkbb'

I've been working with the regex `.scan(/(\[(?:\[??[^\[]*?\]))/)` to find nested brackets

```
s = '3[k2[b]]'
s.scan(/(\[(?:\[??[^\[]*?\]))/)
=> [["[b]"]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = '3[k2[b]]'
nil while s.sub!(/(\d+)\[([^\[\]]*)\]/){$2 * $1.to_i}
s #=> "kbbkbbkbb"
```

Comment: `gsub!` should be significantly faster on long strings when there are many `N[x]N[x]N[x]`-like sequences close to the end.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that might be done within one pass, but it’s easy to achieve with a recursion:

```
%w|4[kl] 3[k2[b]]|.map do |s|
  loop do
    break s if s.gsub!(/(\d+)\[([^\[\]]+)\]/) { $2 * $1.to_i }.nil?
  end
end
#⇒ ["klklklkl", "kbbkbbkbb"]
```

We use here that [`String#gsub!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) returns `nil` on no matches, terminating the whole loop.

Please note, that the code above is *destructing*, that said it *mutates* an input. If you want the original string to stay intact, `dup` it upfront.

Comment: I like how things can be shortened in Ruby.